# After calling function that receives a copy of an object, the original resets

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector

I have a function `decidir()` that receives two objects(jogadores and monstros) that have a vector of pointers inside. After i call that function and it returns, the original objects' vectors have 0 elements each. The class:

```
#ifndef EQUIPE_H
#define EQUIPE_H
#include "Personagem.h"
#define MAX_INTEGRANTES 6

class Equipe
{
public:
    Equipe(short novoMaximoIntegrantes = MAX_INTEGRANTES);
    Equipe(Personagem *novoIntegrantes,short numIntegrantes,short novoMaximoIntegrantes = MAX_INTEGRANTES);
    ~Equipe();
    vector<Personagem*>* getEquipe();
    void adicionarIntegrante(Personagem* integrante);
    void setIntegrante(Personagem* integrante, short posicao);
    int getX();
    void setX(int novoX);
    int getY();
    void setY(int novoY);
    int getZ();
    void setZ(int novoZ);
    Personagem* removerIntegrante(short posicao = MAX_INTEGRANTES);
    Personagem* operator[](short posicao);

private:
    vector<Personagem*>* integrantes;
    short maximoIntegrantes;
    int x, y, z;
};
#endif
```

The function:

```
int* Monstro::decidir(Equipe oponentes, Equipe amigos){
    int decisao[2] = { 0,0 }, nConcorrentes = 0, ataque = 0;
    float rolagem = rand() % 100 + 1;
    float rp = rolagem / 100;
    if (rp < getPrioridadeAtaque())
        ataque = 1;
    if (getNumMagias()){
        rolagem = abs(rolagem - 100);
        rp = rolagem / 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < getNumMagias(); i++){
            if (getPrioriedadeMagias()[i] > rp)
                nConcorrentes++;
        }
        if (ataque){
            decisao[0] = 0;
            do{
                if (oponentes.getEquipe()->size()>3)
                    decisao[1] = rand() % 3;
                else
                    decisao[1] = rand() % oponentes.getEquipe()->size();
                if (oponentes[decisao[1]]->getHP())
                    break;
            } while (true);
        }else{
            if (nConcorrentes){
                rolagem = rand() % (10 * nConcorrentes) + 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= nConcorrentes; i++){
                    if (rolagem > (10 * (i - 1)) && rolagem < (10 * i)){
                        decisao[0] = i+2;
                    }
                }
            }
            do{
                if (getMagia(decisao[0] - 2).getEfeito() == DANO || getMagia(decisao[0] - 2).getEfeito() == DANO_STATUS){
                    decisao[1] = rand() % oponentes.getEquipe()->size();
                    if (oponentes[decisao[1]]->getHP())
                        break;
                }
                else{
                    decisao[1] = rand() % amigos.getEquipe()->size();
                    if (amigos[decisao[1]]->getHP())
                        break;
                }
            } while (true);
        }
    } else{
        do{
            if (oponentes.getEquipe()->size()>3)
                decisao[1] = rand() % 3;
            else
                decisao[1] = rand() % oponentes.getEquipe()->size();
            if (oponentes[decisao[1]]->getHP())
                break;
        } while (true);
    }
    return decisao;
}
```

The code that calls the function:

```
Equipe jogadores , monstros(30);
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
     jogadores.adicionarIntegrante(//long parameter assignment);
}
numMonstros = (rand() % 5 + 1) * jogadores.getEquipe()->size();
for (int i = 0; i < numMonstros; i++){
nomeMonstro = "Slime" + (i>0 ? to_string(i) : "");
monstros.adicionarIntegrante(new Monstro(nomeMonstro, 1, 25, 25, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 18, 1.0, 200, 10));
}
int *decisaoTemp, **decisao, combatenteAtual;
Personagem* combatente=NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < monstros.getEquipe()->size(); i++){
    if (monstros[i]->getHP()){
        combatente = monstros[i];
        combatenteAtual = getCombatenteAtual(combatente, decisao);
        decisaoTemp = combatente->decidir(jogadores, monstros);/*Before this vectors sizes 
        are 6 and a random number times 6*/
        decisao[combatenteAtual][1] = decisaoTemp[0];//Here vector sizes are both 0
        if (decisaoTemp[0] && combatente->getMagia(decisaoTemp[0]).getEfeito() == CURA){
            decisao[combatenteAtual][2] = getCombatenteAlvo(combatentes, monstros, decisaoTemp[1]);
        }
        else{
            decisao[combatenteAtual][2] = getCombatenteAlvo(combatentes, jogadores, decisaoTemp[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in `decidir` function, you have an undefined behaviour once you are returning a pointer to a stack memory.

Comment: @Amadeus should i return a int[] then?

Comment: You have too much code not defined in the sample code to be able to help. If you have functions mutating objects then consider looking at your design and applying proper const declarations to get compiler errors as an aide. Also, try simplifying the problem and create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @BrazilRules This will not solve because you are allocating an object in stack and returning a reference or pointer. The UB remains. But, I believe you have others problems too.

Comment: I don't see a copy constructor, so the copies of the teams will point to the same vector as their sources. If those pointers are deleted in the destructor, you're going to have problems. If they are not deleted in the destructor, you will have other problems. You will have to make a copy constructor. Or better still, do away with the pointer to vector and just have Equipe contain a vector directly.

Comment: @user4581301 I will try. I don't remember why i put it as a pointer in the first place, but i will remember if it gives me trouble. I just remember that it has something with the fact that it is a Pessoa vector, but i store Jogador and Monstro(child classes) objects in it.

Comment: @user4581301 This worked for me. Could you write in answer form so that i can accept it?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Thank you, this is my first question, so i was unsure about the title.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `decidir` you should instead pass parameters by reference. Meaning to just add `&` after the object type: `int* Monstro::decidir(Equipe& oponentes, Equipe& amigos)` this way when the function ends the argument object's destructors won't be called.

When passing objects to function by value, a copy of the object is created. Meaning if your original object had a pointer referencing an address, the copied object will also have a pointer referencing that address. This might cause issues as when the function ends, the copied object will go out of scope and its destructor is called.

Comment: This worked but i decided to follow @user4581301 sugestion and drop the pointer altogether.